# How can I retrieve the following processor stats?

Tags: objective-c, macos

How can I retrieve:

i) Number of total processes
ii) Number of total threads

Note by "total" I mean the total number *in use* **not** the total supported by the system.

I am specifically asking for an Objective-C/C solution on OSX.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `top` and scrape what you're looking for, but I was curious so I dug a bit deeper and found `/usr/include/libproc.h`, and wrote some code:

```
#import <libproc.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pid_t * pids = calloc(0x1000, 1);
    int count = proc_listallpids(pids, 0x1000);

    printf("count=%u\n", count) ;

    for( int index=0; index < count; ++index)
    {
        pid_t pid = pids[ index ] ;

        struct proc_taskinfo taskInfo ;
        /*int result*/ proc_pidinfo( pid, PROC_PIDTASKINFO, 0,  & taskInfo, sizeof( taskInfo ) ) ;

        // fields of taskInfo:
//          uint64_t        pti_virtual_size;   /* virtual memory size (bytes) */
//          uint64_t        pti_resident_size;  /* resident memory size (bytes) */
//          uint64_t        pti_total_user;     /* total time */
//          uint64_t        pti_total_system;
//          uint64_t        pti_threads_user;   /* existing threads only */
//          uint64_t        pti_threads_system;
//          int32_t         pti_policy;     /* default policy for new threads */
//          int32_t         pti_faults;     /* number of page faults */
//          int32_t         pti_pageins;        /* number of actual pageins */
//          int32_t         pti_cow_faults;     /* number of copy-on-write faults */
//          int32_t         pti_messages_sent;  /* number of messages sent */
//          int32_t         pti_messages_received;  /* number of messages received */
//          int32_t         pti_syscalls_mach;  /* number of mach system calls */
//          int32_t         pti_syscalls_unix;  /* number of unix system calls */
//          int32_t         pti_csw;            /* number of context switches */
//          int32_t         pti_threadnum;      /* number of threads in the task */
//          int32_t         pti_numrunning;     /* number of running threads */
//          int32_t         pti_priority;       /* task priority*/

        printf("PID %u:\n", pid);
        printf("\t%20s\t%u\n", "number of threads", taskInfo.pti_threadnum) ;
        printf("\t%20s\t%u\n", "number running threads", taskInfo.pti_numrunning) ;

        printf("\n") ;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

Comment: Your function seems to perfectly return the number of processes. However for the number of threads, it seems to return the correct number of threads for the individual processes, but if I add up the number of threads in each loop, I get an incorrect number of total threads. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: not sure, but I hit on this function by using `sccall` on _top_ to see which system calls it was invoking. `proc_info` (and others) were listed. But it seems to be giving the same info as the _threads_ column in _top_, no?

Comment: where are you getting the other total?

Comment: I know I'm a few years late to this thread but just tried to implement this and had the same question about the total (as shown on top) not matching the sum of the iteration over pids.  Turns out there were a lot of 0 pids at the end of my array, so the loop needs a check of pid>0 before summing.

Comment: I'm even later, and maybe I misunderstood Daniel's comment above, but the point is: that `result` value *IS* useful; it is the size of the buffer written. If it's zero, that means *an error occurred* and the buffer has not been changed. In my case, most (all?) result=0 cases set `errno` to 1, which is EPERM (Or: Permission Denied). Retrying with root permissions eliminated all result=0 cases.

Comment: Hey from 2020. With root permissions is OK too. But without root I can't get ```proc_pidinfo(0, PROC_PIDTASKINFO, ..)``` or another system process pid. Any suggestions how get taskInfo without root permissions?

Comment: @tim I am also facing the same issue. As i want to run the program without root permission and "proc_pidinfo" is getting failed for some of the processes. How to resolve it ?

Comment: @Neel I using this call with root permissions too =( May be in this thread somebody knows how to that without root permissions

Answer (score 2):

Following, roughly, the [source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/top/top-73/libtop.c) for [top(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html), this works when run as root:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_error.h>
#include <mach/mach_vm.h>
#include <mach/task.h>

kern_return_t get_process_thread_count(long *process_count, long *thread_count) {
    kern_return_t   kr;
    processor_set_name_array_t psets;
    processor_set_t pset;
    task_array_t tasks;
    mach_msg_type_number_t  i, j, k, iCount, jCount, kCount;
    long process_accumulator = 0, thread_accumulator = 0;
    mach_port_t host_self = mach_host_self();
    mach_port_t task_self = mach_task_self();
    thread_act_array_t threads;
    int pid;

    if ((kr = host_processor_sets(host_self, &psets, &iCount))) return kr;
    for (i = 0; i < iCount; ++i) {
        if ((kr = host_processor_set_priv(host_self, psets[i], &pset))) return kr;
        if ((kr = processor_set_tasks(pset, &tasks, &jCount))) return kr;
        for (j = 0; j < jCount; ++j) {
            if ((kr = pid_for_task(tasks[j], &pid))) return kr;
            if (pid != 0) {
                /* then the Mach task maps to a BSD process, so */ 
                ++process_accumulator;
                if ((kr = task_threads(tasks[j], &threads, &kCount))) return kr;
                thread_accumulator += kCount;
                for (k = 0; k < kCount; ++k) {
                    if ((kr = mach_port_deallocate(task_self, threads[k]))) return kr;
                }
                if ((kr = mach_vm_deallocate(task_self,
                                             (mach_vm_address_t)(uintptr_t)threads,
                                             kCount * sizeof(*threads)))) return kr;
            }
            if ((kr = mach_port_deallocate(task_self, tasks[j]))) return kr;
        }
        if ((kr = mach_vm_deallocate(task_self,
                                     (mach_vm_address_t)(uintptr_t)tasks,
                                     kCount * sizeof(*tasks)))) return kr;
        if ((kr = mach_port_deallocate(task_self, psets[j]))) return kr;
    }
    if ((kr = mach_vm_deallocate(task_self,
                                 (vm_address_t)psets,
                                 iCount * sizeof(*psets)))) return kr;
    *process_count = process_accumulator;
    *thread_count = thread_accumulator;
    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    long process_count, thread_count;
    kern_return_t r;
    if ((r = get_process_thread_count(&process_count, &thread_count))) {
        mach_error("get_process_thread_count error: ", r);
        return 1;
    };
    printf("%ld processes, %ld threads\n", process_count, thread_count);
    return 0;
}
```

Obtaining information about all processes on the system requires elevated privileges, so if you need to do this as an unprivileged user, calling top or ps via NSTask is probably a better option, as they're already setuid root.

Final note: as (lazily) written, this code leaks both memory and Mach ports on failure.

Answer (score 0):

For Objective C, you can use [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do a system call to `sysctl -aw` to get things like

```
kern.maxproc = xxxx
kern.num_threads: xxxxx
```

Comment: Or you could just call `sysctl()` directly!

Comment: @KellyQuinnNicholes Thanks! Could you please provide a code example of how I would do it?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Riddler: Why don't you read the documentation for `NSTask` or `sysctl()`, give it a shot, and let us know if you have specific difficulties?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan 1)I couldn't find a "kern.num_threads" argument for the sysctl function. Are there any alternatives? 2)I looked at the documentation and it states that maxproc returns the total number of threads that *can* run on the system, not the total number of threads currently running. Is there a way I can retrieve the total number of threads currently running? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `kern.num_threads` can be retrieved with the `sysctlbyname()` variant. But I don't think that the info you want is made available by any system call. Why do you want this information? What are you trying to build?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I am trying to create a type of system monitor.

Comment: Well, `top` gives the number of threads per process--at least allocated, so I assume the info is available in some way.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Sorry, I'n not in a position where I can disclose more information.

Comment: @nielsbot Top was perfect! Could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I posted an answer and some C sample code that gets what you want as well.